# INSTEAD OF INSERT/UPDATE trigger error, "Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition"

Tags: sql, sql-server, triggers

In SQL Server I am trying to write an `INSTEAD OF INSERT` trigger on a view that will alter multiple tables when edited through MS Access. The idea is to have an insert statement for records that don't exist and an update for when an associated ID is found. When I use the following trigger it works as intended...

```
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

ALTER TRIGGER [ofs].[IO_Trig_OFS] 
ON [ofs].[V_OFS_CONTRACTORS]  
INSTEAD OF INSERT  
AS  
BEGIN  
    SET NOCOUNT ON  

    -- Check for duplicate Contact. If there is no duplicate, do an insert.  
    IF (NOT EXISTS (SELECT P.ContactID  
                    FROM [ofs].[OFS_CONTACTS] P, inserted I  
                    WHERE P.ContactID = I.ContactID))  
        INSERT INTO [ofs].[OFS_CONTACTS]  
            SELECT 
                [ContractorID],
                [ContactFirstName], [ContactLastName],
                [ContactPriority], [JobTitle],
                [EmailAddress], [WorkPhone], [WorkExtension],
                [CellPhone], [ContactSource]  
            FROM 
                inserted  
    ELSE  
        --If there is a duplicate, change to UPDATE so that there will not  
        --be a duplicate key violation error.  
        UPDATE [ofs].[OFS_CONTACTS]  
        SET [ContactFirstName] = I.ContactFirstName,
            [ContactLastName] = I.ContactLastName,
            [ContactPriority] = I.ContactPriority,
            [JobTitle] = I.JobTitle,
            [EmailAddress] = I.EmailAddress,
            [WorkPhone] = I.WorkPhone,
            [WorkExtension] = I.WorkExtension,
            [CellPhone] = I.CellPhone,
            [ContactSource] = I.ContactSource  
        FROM 
            [ofs].[OFS_CONTACTS] E, inserted I  
        WHERE 
            E.ContactID = I.ContactID  
END;
```

But when I add another table to edit for inserts/updates in the same manner I get this error:

> Msg 213, Level 16, State 1, Procedure IO_Trig_OFS, Line 11
>   Column name or number of supplied values does not match table definition.

I have a feeling it is poor syntax but it would help to get another set of eyes on it. Thanks!

Comment: Double check the table definition for [ofs].[OFS_CONTRACTORS]. The error you get is self explanatory: you either have a different number of columns or the order is not the correct one when you insert the data. It is a good practice to add the list of column names on the INSERT statement.

Comment: Also you might want to use a MERGE statement instead of the conditional INSERT/UPDATE.

Comment: [Bad habits to kick : using old-style JOINs](https://sqlblog.org/2009/10/08/bad-habits-to-kick-using-old-style-joins) - that old-style *comma-separated list of tables* style was replaced with the *proper* ANSI `JOIN` syntax in the ANSI-**92** SQL Standard (**more than 20 years** ago) and its use is discouraged

Comment: I would recommend to **always** explicitly specify the columns you want to insert *into* in your code - that way, you can be sure the number (and type) of columns matches what your `SELECT` will return: `INSERT INTO [ofs].[OFS_CONTACTS] (col1, col2, ...., colN) SELECT .....`

Comment: Awesome. Thanks for all the recommendations.

Comment: @marc_s Your suggestion to change the syntax to `INSERT INTO [ofs].[OFS_CONTACTS] (col1, col2, ...., colN) SELECT .....` solved all my problems.